# How can I eliminate the heavy lag

Tags: drivers

The lag is unbearable when I use blender, specifically when I move objects. I haven't even tried rendering. I just bought a refurbished Dell 780 Optiplex with Windows 7, 4GB RAM, and a Quad Core Q9300 processor. The graphics driver is an Intel GMA 4500. I understand that hardware may need to be added or upgraded, but I'm still learning about all this stuff. I've searched forums and youtube and haven't found the solution to my scenario. Any advice is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Best thing you can do in your situation; Get a new computer/hardware, or keep your polycount low

Comment: Probably first you should detect what the lag is, then start finding options for upgrade / optimizing. Polycount is not always something causing crash / slow work. I'm not sure but that graphics card might probably be the weakest thing here, it [doesn't appear to support OpenGL 3.x](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/181314-OpenGL-version-for-Intel-GMA-4500) required for new Blender 2.8